# Is it possible to register a generic interface without specifying generic types in Unity?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

Let's say I have the following:

```
 public interface IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>  {
        TTo Translate(TFrom fromObj);
    }

  public class IdentityDataTranslator<T> : IDataTranslator<T, T> {
        public T Translate(T fromObj) {
            return fromObj;
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way where I can do:

```
   IdentityDataTranslator<A> trA = UnityContainer.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, A>>()
   IdentityDataTranslator<B> trB = UnityContainer.Resolve<IDataTranslator<B, B>>()
   IdentityDataTranslator<C> trc = UnityContainer.Resolve<IDataTranslator<C, C>>()
```

And for all these resolves (assume I don't know the types of the generics that will be resolved) I would like Unity to return an instance of the IdentityDataTranslator with the appropriate generic. Is there a way to register somehow with Unity to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `assume I don't know the types of the generics that will be resolved`?

Comment: When I resolve I will always resolve as Container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<X,Y>. If it happens that X,Y are the same types then the IdentityTranslator should be used. Otherwise, a translator for X,Y should be retrieved from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understood your question you can use `InjectionFactory` to set how to resolve the current type. It looks like this:

```
    // It's a test implementation of IDataTranslator<From, To>
    public class DataTranslator<TFrom, TTo> : IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>
    {
        TTo IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>.Translate(TFrom fromObj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    ...
    var strResolve = "notSameResolve";
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataTranslator<,>), typeof(DataTranslator<,>), strResolve);
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataTranslator<,>),
        new InjectionFactory(
            (con, type, str) =>
            {
                var argumets = type.GetGenericArguments();
                if (argumets[0] != argumets[1])
                {
                    return con.Resolve(type, strResolve);
                }

                return con.Resolve(typeof(IdentityDataTranslator<>).MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
            }));

    var trA = (IdentityDataTranslator<A>)container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, A>>();
    var trAData = (DataTranslator<A, B>)container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, B>>();
```

So if you try to resolve `IDataTranslator<A, B>` with `InjectionFactory` that is above, you get a `DataTranslator<A, B>` and get `IdentityDataTranslator<A>` when try to resolve `IDataTranslator<A, A>` with the same arguments.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I'll try it on Monday! Thanks a lot... would have never figured this out myself. Great to learn something new!

Comment: What would happen if I do Container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A,B>()? In that case it should look in the Container for a DataTranslator from A -> B which WILL NOT be an IdentityDataTranslator but some other translator that I will register with the Container? The Identity translator should only be used if the fromType = toType... I'll try it out Monday but is this going to be the behavior of the code above?

Comment: @Denis In the previoues answer's version you get `IdentityDataTranslator<A>` when try to resolve `IDataTranslator<A,B>`. I fixed it, so now it returns `IdentityDataTranslator<A>` when you try resolve `IDataTranslator` with the same arguments and returns `DataTranslator` (test implementation) when you ty to resolve `IDataTranslator` with the different arguments. So please check the answer.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could match the number of generic parameters between the interface and class by creating a new interface which inherits the original interface that had two generic parameters.  It is assumed that those two parameters are known to always be the same.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static IUnityContainer container;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataTranslator<>), typeof(IdentityDataTranslator<>));

            IdentityDataTranslator<string> translator = container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<string>>() as IdentityDataTranslator<string>;
            string result = translator.Translate("12351");
        }
    }

    public interface IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>
    {
        TTo Translate(TFrom fromObj);
    }

    public interface IDataTranslator<T> : IDataTranslator<T,T>
    {
    }

    public class IdentityDataTranslator<T> : IDataTranslator<T>
    {
        public T Translate(T fromObj)
        {
            return fromObj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I right understood, @Denis want a something that looks like this:
`container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataTranslator<,>), typeof(IdentityDataTranslator<>));
            var trA = container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, A>>();`
Unfortunatly without injection factory we cannot register types with different parameters number

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria updated answer - closer to correct you think?

Comment: Yes, now it's closer.

Comment: When I resolve I will always resolve as Container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<X,Y>. If it happens that X,Y are the same types then the IdentityTranslator should be used. Otherwise, a translator for X,Y should be retrieved from the container.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach to your question.  Instead of focusing entirely on registration let's also consider how to resolve to the correct type.

The idea is to register the typical case mapping a `IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>` to a `DataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>`.  The next step is to create a Unity container extension to map the special case where TFrom is the same type as TTo while resolving `IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>`.

Given:

```
public class A { }

public class B { }

public interface IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>
{
    TTo Translate(TFrom fromObj);
}

public class DataTranslator<TFrom, TTo> : IDataTranslator<TFrom, TTo>
{
    public TTo Translate(TFrom fromObj)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TTo>();
    }
}

public class IdentityDataTranslator<T> : IDataTranslator<T, T>
{
    public T Translate(T fromObj)
    {
        return fromObj;
    }
}
```

Next create a container extension to handle the IdentityDataTranslator:

```
public class IdentityGenericsExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private readonly Type identityGenericType;
    private readonly Type baseType;

    public IdentityGenericsExtension(Type identityGenericType, Type baseType)
    {
        // Verify that Types are open generics with the correct number of arguments
        // and that they are compatible (IsAssignableFrom).
        this.identityGenericType = identityGenericType;
        this.baseType = baseType;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.Context.Strategies.Add(
            new IdentityGenericsBuildUpStrategy(this.identityGenericType, this.baseType),
                UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }

    private class IdentityGenericsBuildUpStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        private readonly Type identityGenericType;
        private readonly Type baseType;

        public IdentityGenericsBuildUpStrategy(Type identityGenericType, Type baseType)
        {
            this.identityGenericType = identityGenericType;
            this.baseType = baseType;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            if (context.OriginalBuildKey.Type.IsGenericType &&
                context.OriginalBuildKey.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == this.baseType)
            {
                // Get generic args
                Type[] argTypes = context.BuildKey.Type.GetGenericArguments();

                if (argTypes.Length == 2 && argTypes.Distinct().Count() == 1)
                {
                    context.BuildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(
                        this.identityGenericType.MakeGenericType(argTypes[0]),
                        context.BuildKey.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is before type mapping check to see if the requested type is a `IDataTranslator<T,K>` and that there are two generic arguments and both generic arguments are the same type.  If so then the `IdentityDataTranslator<T>` is set as the new build key (instead of the expected `DataTranslator<T,K>`.

Missing is validation of the types to ensure they are the correct shape and are assignable.

Finally, setup the container and run some tests to ensure we get an `IdentityDataTranslator` when the from and to types are the same:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(
    new IdentityGenericsExtension(typeof(IdentityDataTranslator<>), typeof(IDataTranslator<,>)));

container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataTranslator<,>), typeof(DataTranslator<,>));

// Since A is different than B we get back a DataTranslator<A,B>
var dataTranslator = container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, B>>();
Debug.Assert(dataTranslator.GetType() == typeof(DataTranslator<A, B>));

// Since A is the same as A we get back a IdentityDataTranslator<A>
var identityTranslator = container.Resolve<IDataTranslator<A, A>>();
Debug.Assert(identityTranslator.GetType() == typeof(IdentityDataTranslator<A>));
```

The above approach works but there might be a strictly registration based approach that I didn't think of that also works and enforces your constraints.

Comment: This is a very clean solution. Thank you